# Is there a way to cancel a sending message?

Tags: sms

While the message is "sending", I discovered that I had sent to the wrong person. Isn't there anything you can do about this? I used to use Nokia. In those older phones (or systems) you simply press the "C" botton to the right and the sending message is aborted.

Answer (score 7):

Airplane Mode  immediately..then force stop, then clear the data, the restart phone... Worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of is by killing the Message application. But I'm not sure if the message sending is done by the Message application itself or if it passes the message to other process or android core to do the real transfer of message.

Anyways you can check by going to Menu -> Settings-> Manage applications -> Select all tab and select Message and click Force stop.

Comment: I'd venture a guess that the delay is caused by the Messaging application waiting for a response from the cell tower that the message has been successfully sent. If that's the case, killing the app won't work.

Comment: Killing messaging service works..

Comment: I'd just pull the battery out.. that'll always kill

Comment: I think by the time one navigates to the screen where the "Force Stop" button is, the message will probably have reached the destination and most likely have been sent from the phone. What OP needs is something like an UNDO in Gmail which basically sends a message after a specified x seconds delay, allowing a user to cancel the message.

Answer (score 1):

While the message is "sending" press and hold the comment/text massage. A menu option should appear giving you the option to cancel message before it sends. Airplane mode is a good one that'll work too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Cancel SMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.tonee.undosms) - works as I mentioned in the comment above.

There's a delay of one minute before sending, thereby allowing a user to cancel the send within a minute of typing out the message.

Be warned, the app adds a bookmark and a search shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is, putting the phone into Airplane Mode. So the sending message will be cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it with the [SMS UNDO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ioptime.blocksms) app for android. It runs in the background and is very easy to use. Also you can set up timer when it will be active and the time the message will be put on hold.

Comment: Considering the number of installs the app has as of now, I suppose this answer did nothing more than shameless promotion.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PVLL](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Pull.pullapp). The app puts a delay of 5 seconds before sending, called the "5 second rule". Works for me.

It also has a feature that lets you schedule texts in the future, and there's a sharing layer on top of SMS that lets you discuss your conversations. I use it instead of taking screenshots or cut and paste.

Comment: So far you have two answers on this site, both to promote the same app. What's your relationship with this app? It's important to be clear about this so other users can judge your recommendation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

just delete the text while its sending (click and hold on the message)
if the text is not too embarrassing just tell the person who it accidentally got sent to that you didn't mean to send it to them and that it was an accident. or every time you send a text you could create a new text (by typing in/searching for the correct phone number or contact name within your phone's address book)with the correct person's name instead of texting them from the list of names from previous texts that shows up when you open the texting app (to avoid sending it to the wrong person in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

The c button you mentioned works in Nokia only if the message stays in outbox which sometimes don't work always. The closest option you can get is by using Textra SMS from play store and set the delay sending SMS option to 9seconds. If you happen to send a message to a wrong recipient, you can cancel the SMS by pressing the x button after pressing the send button.